# How to make use Bounded Types in Generic functions in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm not seeing any syntax for creating bounded generic type specifications in the TypeScript documentation as in some other languages.

Is there anything like

```
   class Foo<Bar implements Sortable> { ... }
```

or some similar construct?

I've seen that you can use `&` in parameter type specifiers, as in

```
add(item:  ListItem & Sortable) {...}
```

but that syntax doesn't seem to work on class declarations with generic types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question but if you change `implements` to `extends` it should work:

```
interface Sortable { ... };
class Foo<Bar extends Sortable> { ... };
```

Comment: Oh.  Well there you go.  I'm not used to the notion of a class "extending" (as opposed to 'implementing' an interface.  But I guess it works in TypeScript.

Comment: @user1023110 In TypeScript, a class also cannot extend an interface (`implements` is correct). `extends Sortable` is a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) of type parameter `Bar` used in class `Foo`.

Comment: "extends" is a funny word to use when expressing the notion of "constraint"

Comment: @user1023110: The way I read something like `A<B extends C>` is "constrain A to type B that extends C" rather than "A is constrained to C". I.e. the constraint is "types that extend C" not "C"