# Limit generic type (<T>(p: T)=>T, T can be only some specific types)

Tags: typescript

Any one knows how to make typescript for a function look like this?

```
const fn = <T>(props: T) => { ...logics which will reuse <T>...}
```

But T can be only one of boolean or { b: string; }

Comment: `<T extends boolean | {[k: string]: number}>(...) => ...`

Comment: `T extends Whatever`? Read the docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make use Bounded Types in Generic functions in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59596159/how-to-make-use-bounded-types-in-generic-functions-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

Use unions if type can only be specific types.

```
const funSignature = (props: Boolean | String) => {
```

//  ...logics which will reuse <Boolean | String>...
}

Comment: `Boolean` and `String` are the wrong types. They correspond to the wrapper objects created by `new`ing the `String` or `Boolean` functions. Use the `boolean` and  `string` types instead

Answer (score -1):

You could also create your own type.

See below.

```js
type Struct = string | number | boolean;

const fn = <T extends Struct>(props: T) => { ...logics which will reuse <T>...}
```